# What happens if rsync is scheduled to do backup, but remote location is unavailable?

Tags: rsync, backup

I'm thinking of creating a sync/backup routine with rsync for some crucial files between my Desktop computer and Laptop. The point is not to use a Cloud service. I would set up an automated schedule to perform the task (daily, weekly, etc).

Question: What happens if one of the locations are offline when rsync is attempted?

- The laptop (source) cannot access the desktop computer (destination).
- Or, the desktop computer (source) cannot access the laptop (destination).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two endpoints cannot see each other then no data will be transferred. On each scheduled run, a successful and complete connection will result in all outstanding data being transferred.

However, it sounds like you really shouldn't be using `rsync` for this task, though, as it is unidirectional. If you can have updates going both ways you should consider something like `unison` to handle this.